# Proguard android app which uses support lib crashes

Tags: android, proguard, android-support-library

I've got android app wihch uses support lib. It was obfuscated with Proguard, and itcrashes on Home Activity on code:

```
` @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu); //ith crashes here
        return true;        
    } `
```

throwing:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.util.Xml.asAttributeSet at android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater.inflate(Unknown Source) at com.sample.mobile.HomeActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(Unknown Source)
```

I've enabled proGuard using :

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

in project.properties

My config file looks like this:

```
-libraryjars libs
-libraryjars C:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.util.Xml..** { *; }

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.billing.IInAppBillingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}
-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
    public void *(android.view.View);
    public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}
```

I added many thing, cos I was looking for solution for this problem.

Comment: What class does HomeActivity extend?

Comment: solution was to add "-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }" line in the config file

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure how it is happened. But adding following line to proguard rules solve the problem.

-keep class org.xmlpull.v1.** { *; }

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer.  In my case I have to use both your answer and -dontwarn org.xmlpull.v1.** because the app uses kSoap2.